# How to achieve stacked styling effect with html and css?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image]

How is this styling achieved using html and css? It looks like three divs, however when inspected through the console, it appears that `::before` might be being used.

Also does anyone know what this kind of style might be called so I can update the title of this question to be more specific?

I took this image and example from here http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into code, it's pretty simple to find how they achieved this effect. Stacked `box-shadows`.

```
.footer:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
        0 8px 0 -3px #f6f6f6,
        0 9px 1px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
        0 16px 0 -6px #f6f6f6,
        0 17px 2px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

But surely there are more ways of doing this, depending on your needs.